# Can't remove space below images in sliced image for webpage

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, spacing

The link to the page is [westvillenyc.com/super-draft](http://westvillenyc.com/locations/super-draft/). That little  black space beneath the row of images is so frustrating! I have tried editing my stylesheet and my html code to no avail. Here is the html coding I have so far:

HTML coding:

```
<table class="address_table2" style="height: 341px;" width="700">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td align="center" width="681" height="0"><a href="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/SuperBowlHalfPage.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att-21167"><img class="wp-image-21167 aligncenter" src="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1-1024x393.jpg" alt="1" width="681" height="261" /> </a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att-21168"><img class="alignnone wp-image-21168" src="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/3.jpg" alt="3" width="212" height="48" /></a><a href="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/4.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att-21169"><img class="alignnone wp-image-21169" src="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/4.jpg" alt="4" width="148" height="48" /></a><a href="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/5.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att-21170"><img class="alignnone wp-image-21170" src="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/5.jpg" alt="5" width="144" height="48" /></a><a href="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/6.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att-21171"><img class="alignnone wp-image-21171k;" src="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/6.jpg" alt="6" width="179" height="48" /></a><a href="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/7.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att-21173"><img class="alignnone wp-image-21173" src="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/7.jpg" alt="7" width="286" height="76" /></a><a href="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/7-2.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att-21172"><img class="alignnone wp-image-21172" src="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/7-2.jpg" alt="7 (2)" width="125" height="76" /></a><a href="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/9.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att-21174"><img class="alignnone wp-image-21174" src="http://westvillenyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/9.jpg" alt="9" width="276" height="76" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Css coding:

```
.address_table2 {

    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is this what you wish to achieve? http://imgur.com/a/tbeBR

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset the top image `margin` which is pushing the ones below down.

CSS:

```
img.wp-image-21167.aligncenter {
  margin: 0;
}
```

2. Push last row images up.

CSS:

```
img.alignnone.wp-image-21172,
img.alignnone.wp-image-21173,
img.alignnone.wp-image-21174 {
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

[image]